# I get error: call of overloaded ‘max(Cents&, Cents&)’ is ambiguous

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

1.. I'm testing following code which uses template
Source code is originated from this learncpp tutorial
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/132-function-template-instances/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

// ======================================================================
template <typename T>
const T& max(const T& x,const T& y)
{
  return (x>y)?x:y;
}

// ======================================================================
class Cents
{
private:
  int m_cents;
public:
  Cents(int cents):m_cents(cents)
  {
  }

  friend bool operator>(const Cents &c1,const Cents &c2)
  {
    return (c1.m_cents>c2.m_cents);
  }

  int get_val()
  {
    m_cents;
  }
};

// ======================================================================
int main()
{
  Cents nickle(5);
  Cents dime(10);

  Cents bigger=max(nickle,dime);
  // std::cout<<"bigger: "<<bigger.get_val()<<std::endl;
  // bigger: 1471225424

  return 0;
}
```

And I get this error

```
error: call of overloaded ‘max(Cents&, Cents&)’ is ambiguous
   Cents bigger=max(nickle,dime);
```

What's wrong with the code?

2.. And how can I print result?
For example, I tried `std::cout<<"bigger: "<<bigger<<std::endl;`
But I ran into following error which says there is no overloaded operator << for bigger(Cent type object)

```
error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
   std::cout<<"bigger: "<<bigger<<std::endl;
```

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘Cents’)
   std::cout<<"bigger: "<<bigger<<std::endl;
```

Comment: Concerning `std::cout << "bigger: " << bigger << std::endl`: I don't see you define a suitable `operator <<` that could take an object of type `Cents` anywhere, so what exactly do you expect this should do?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I edited code to specify what I would like to do with "returned bigger object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace `std` also contains a function template named [`max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) which has a signature basically identical to your `max` function template. While you did not explicitly include the header in which `std::max` is officially defined (`<algorithm>`), an implementation may include any library header from any other library header [[res.on.headers]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/res.on.headers#1), so it is perfectly legal (and something that code using the standard library must expect to deal with) that `std::max` ends up being declared in namespace `std` in your case. The

```
using namespace std;
```

directive at the top will then introduce the `std::max` function template into the global namespace. Thus, at any point after this using directive, unqualified name lookup will find two function templates named `max` in the global namespace that have identical signatures and, thus, your call to `max` will be ambiguous (it cannot be decided which function should be called as they're both equally valid choices). To fix the issue, get rid of the `using namespace std;` (recommended) or explicitly identify the target of your `max` function call via qualified name, e.g.:

```
Cents bigger = ::max(nickle, dime);
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved error with max(). And could you advise how to print returned object from max()? I tried to create public get_val() which returns m_cents. So, as soon as I got bigger object from max(), I tried bigger.get_val(). But value looked like garbage value like 1471225424